# How to test a component trigger "click" updates a data property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

What is the proper way to test that my method is called? The following is a simple example:

### My Component

```html
<template>
  <button ref="btn1" @click="doSomething('btn1')"></button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      btn1: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething(btnId) {
      this[btnId] = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

### My Test

```js
test('btn1 was clicked', async () => {
  const btn1 = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'btn1' })
  await btn1.trigger('click')
  expect(wrapper.vm.btn1).toBeTruthy()
})
```

The issue is `wrapper.vm.btn1` is always **false**. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `this[btnId] = true;` to `this.btnId = true;`

Comment: Please explain if this is an attempt to answer the OP question or is a new question for a problem you are having